# How to print more than one ticket on blue tooth thermal printer using flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

I was using esc_pos_bluetooth flutter package to print ticket. It works fine for one ticket. But I couldn't print more than one ticket.

Can u please suggest any other package which i can use or how i can use the above package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of using a another package , just call the function twice .
that's what i did for my project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).